# ffmpeg output in Audacity

Tags: ffmpeg

I wanted to split the audio track of a mp4 file each receiving different filter then merge to an output mp4 file. Please note I do not wanted series filter but rather parallel filter and then merge.

I came up with the following command.
`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:a]asplit[audio1][audio2];[audio1]highpass=f=200:p=1:t=h:w=50;[audio2]lowpass=f=700:p=1:t=h:w=200;[audio1][audio2]amerge=inputs=2[out]" -map "[out]" -map 0:v -c:v copy -map 0:s? -c:s copy -ac 2 -y output.mp4`

this output will play on Vlc and mpv. However, when I try to open it in Audacity, I get:
[image]
Why I do get this? I assume the index[05] is the correct audio output.
This raise the question, which audio track is playing when opened in Vlc? How can I create an output which has only one final audio track?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't leave filter outputs unlabelled. They are treated as sinks if not consumed by any downstream filters and implicitly mapped for output.

Use

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:a]asplit[audio1][audio2];[audio1]highpass=f=200:p=1:t=h:w=50[audio1];[audio2]lowpass=f=700:p=1:t=h:w=200[audio2];[audio1][audio2]amerge=inputs=2[out]" -map "[out]" -map 0:v -c:v copy -map 0:s? -c:s copy -ac 2 -y output.mp4`

Comment: Thanks, solved the problem! Wish ffmpeg had clearer documantion.

Comment: I tried to do the same think for aiff or wav files with the `following:'fmpeg -i input.aiff -filter_complex "[0:a]asplit[audio1][audio2];[audio1]highpass=f=200:p=1:t=h:w=50[audio1];[audio2]lowpass=f=700:p=1:t=h:w=200[audio2];[audio1]   [audio2]amerge=inputs=2[out]" -map "[out]"  -ac 2 -y output.aiff`   But get the following errors: [Parsed_amerge_6 @ 0x7fa5e6601080] No channel layout for input 1
    Last message repeated 1 times
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x7fa5e640f980] The following filters could not cho

Comment: Do you know the exact channel layout?

Comment: No. How do I check that? ffprobe? if so for aiff I get:Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16be, 44100 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 1411 kb/s   and for wav get: Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 1411 kb/s